# Checking null in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel blade I have a button that if record is not empty, it calls a `JQuery` function

```
@if(!empty($first_step_validation))
    <button onclick="validate_first_step()" class="next action-button" type="button" name="next">(Save & Next)</button>
@else
    <button class="next action-button" type="button" name="next"> (Save & Next)</button>
@endif
```

JQuery function

```
function validate_first_step() {

var target_value_entry = $('input[name="target_value"]').val();
var tag = {!! $workstep->subprocess_id !!} ; 

var first_step_min = {!! $first_step_validation->min_value !!} ;
var first_step_max = {!! $first_step_validation->max_value !!} ;

var first_step_target = {!! $first_step_validation->target_value !!} ;

console.log(first_step_min);
console.log(first_step_max);
console.log(first_step_target);

if(target_value_entry > first_step_min && target_value_entry < first_step_max) {
     alert('You are doing well.');
}
if(target_value_entry < first_step_min) {
     alert(`Warning! Your entry for this step is below the expected target value of: ${first_step_min}`)
}
if(target_value_entry > first_step_max) {
     alert(`Warning! Your entry for this step is above the expected target value of: ${first_step_max}`)
}
```

}

The function works good except when the record is empty I get error

```
Attempt to read min_value on null
```

I checked the variable `$first_step_validation` and found it null, so why the function was called from the first place?

Also if I change the variables in the function from

```
var first_step_min = {!! $first_step_validation->min_value !!} ;
```

To

```
var first_step_min = { $first_step_validation->min_value ?? ""} ;
```

The error goes away, but I get `console error`

```
function $first_step_validation is not defined
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or a jQuery problem? Why not check what Laravel prints and adjust that if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$first_step_validation is null when the data is empty. you should call your function only when $first_step_validation is not null

```
@unless(empty($first_step_validation))
    <script>
        function validate_first_step() {
        }
    </script>
@endunless
```